# how to fetch a selected value from a text file using a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this (myfile.txt)

```
{"projectStatus":{"status":"ERROR","conditions":[{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_bugs","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"2"},
{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_reliability_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"3"},
{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_security_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"2"},
{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_maintainability_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"1"},
{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_code_smells","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"17"},
{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_vulnerabilities","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"2"},
{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"coverage","comparator":"LT","errorThreshold":"90","actualValue":"80.3"},
{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage","comparator":"LT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"90","actualValue":"7.826086956521739"}],
"periods":[{"index":1,"mode":"previous_version","date":"2021-11-04T14:47:41+0000"}],"ignoredConditions":false}}
```

I have to pick `"actualValue":"7.826086956521739"` which is with `"metricKey":"new_coverage"`

then expected output is (actualValue)

```
7.826086956521739
```

this is what I tried

```
sed -n 's/"metricKey":"new_coverage" "actualValue": //p' myfile.txt
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

**Note: I am not allowed to use jq or a general purpose scripting language (JavaScript, Python etc).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*"metricKey":"new_coverage".*"actualValue":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' file
7.826086956521739
```

Answer (score 2):

For Future readers in case anyone needs an answer in `jq`(Adding this answer here, though OP says OP can't use it). With `jq` which is json aware tool, you could try following answer. Written and tested with shown samples. Using `jq`'s `-r` option to get data in raw output form and then selecting appropriate component value where checking if value of metricKey is `new_coverage` then print it's actualValue component value.

```
jq -r '.[] | .conditions[] | select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue' Input_file
```

***OR*** a non-one liner form of above solution:

```
jq -r '.[]    | 
.conditions[] | 
select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows: `7.826086956521739`

Answer (score 0):

```
{m,g,n}awk 'NF*=NF==3' FS='^.+"metricKey":"new_coverage".+actualValue":"|[^0-9]+$' OFS=

7.826086956521739
```

|

```
{m,g,n}awk '$!NF = sprintf("%.*s",NF*=NF==3,$-_)' OFS= \
              FS='^.+"metricKey":"new_coverage".+actualValue":"|[^0-9]+$' 

7.8
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to connect myfile.txt with this commands? I tried ` {m,g,n}awk 'NF*=NF==3' FS='^.+"metricKey":"new_coverage".+actualValue":"|[^0-9]+$' OFS= myfile.txt` but then I had an error "-bash: mawk: command not found"

Comment: @Zero5 : `"{m,g,n}awk"` is not a valid command - it meant any one of `mawk`, `gawk`, `nawk`, or just any non-BusyBox `awk`