# How fetch a value from a file with given conditions (using a shell script)

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have to read a file (myfile.txt) and fetch the particular value matching with conditions and writing to a new file (newfile.txt).

I have to write `"actualValue"` matching with `"status":"ERROR"` , `"metricKey":"new_coverage"` to newfile.txt only if conditions are matched.
otherwise I have to write newfile.txt empty.

if `myfile.txt`

```
{"projectStatus":{"status":"ERROR","conditions":[{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_bugs","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"2"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_reliability_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"3"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_security_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"2"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_maintainability_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"1"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_code_smells","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"20"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_vulnerabilities","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"2"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"coverage","comparator":"LT","errorThreshold":"90","actualValue":"80.9"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage","comparator":"LT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"90","actualValue":"14.810126582278482"}],"periods":[{"index":1,"mode":"previous_version","date":"2021-11-04T14:47:41+0000"}],"ignoredConditions":false}}
```

expected output on newfile.txt:

```
14.810126582278482
```

if `myfile.txt`

```
{"projectStatus":{"status":"ERROR","conditions":[{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_bugs","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"0"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_reliability_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"1"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_security_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"1"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_maintainability_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"1","actualValue":"1"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_code_smells","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"0"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_vulnerabilities","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"0","actualValue":"0"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"coverage","comparator":"LT","errorThreshold":"90","actualValue":"19.7"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_coverage","comparator":"LT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"90","actualValue":"100.0"}],"periods":[{"index":1,"mode":"previous_version","date":"2022-06-29T05:54:05+0100"}],"ignoredConditions":false}}
```

expected output on newfile.txt:

`empty` - (I have to keep newfile.txt empty)

this is what I tried

```
sed -n 's/.*"status":"ERROR".*"metricKey":"new_coverage".*"actualValue":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

I referred:

[how to fetch a selected value from a text file using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743044/how-to-fetch-a-selected-value-from-a-text-file-using-a-shell-script)

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

**Note: I am not allowed to use Jq or general purpose scripting language (JavaScript, Python etc).**

Comment: no. only shell allowed

Comment: Your `sed` command should be working fine, what is the error?

Comment: it works with "status":"OK" also. that is the problem. I only have fetch the value with "status":"ERROR", "metricKey":"new_coverage"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `grep` you could try following code, written and tested with your shown samples. This will make sure your to print values of `actualValue` only if `status` is `ERROR` and `metricKey` is `"new_coverage`

```
grep -oP '"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage".*?"actualValue":"\K([^"]*)' Input_file
```

Comment: Since OP's samples are updated so I have added GNU `grep` solution with Lazy match `.*?` to get nearest match possible and it worked with latest samples of OP.

Comment: your answer seems works fine now. now I am checking it with applying to the final script. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ee '/.*status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage([^:]*:){4}"([^"]*).*/ ! d ;{s//\2/;wnewfile.txt' -e '}' input_file
14.810126582278482
$ cat newfile.txt
14.810126582278482
```

If the match is not found, the line is deleted and an empty file is written instead

Answer (score 1):

If there are no nested curly's, you can match the opening curly and match any character except curly's using a negated character class `[^{}]*` until you reach the `actualValue`, and then capture that value in group 1.

The pattern could look like:

```
.*{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage"[^{}]*"actualValue":"([^"{}]*)".*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dpzU77/1)

Example in `sed`

```
sed -n 's/.*{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage"[^{}]*"actualValue":"\([^"{}]*\)".*/\1/p' file
```

Output

```
14.810126582278482
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do that using sed

```
 sed -Ee '/.*status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage([^:]*:)
{4}"([^"]*).*/ ! d ;{s//\2/;file.txt' -e '}' log_file
```